# Opensource or Free Fingerprint Reader SDK

Tags: java, sdk, open-source, fingerprint

I am starting my final year project and need an SDK for a fingerprint reader. I have a [microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/d/fingerprint-reader) fingerprint scanner. I am planning to use Java & Eclipse under Windows 8 to develop the project.

If anybody has heard / uses a free SDK I would like to hear from you !

Comment: A fingerprint reader for **Android**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to go with [libfprint](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fprint/libfprint) in the end. I have it running under Ubuntu 11.10 (12.04 does not work with vmplayer yet) in vmplayer. Works a charm !

Comment: p.s Wrapped it in jlibfprint (http://code.google.com/p/jlibfprint/) so I could program in Java.

Comment: would jlibfprint still work if i use it in a java applet ? i am thinking for interaction with a windows user front of the browser .

Comment: @Tomcelic can you tell me how to integrate it with android studio. if you know...

Comment: @M.Usman - I only used it with Java desktop - sorry.

Answer (score 4):

I know only [VeriFinger Embedded SDK](http://www.neurotechnology.com/verifinger-embedded.html) it's free 30-day Trial.