# Capture and compare finger print image

Tags: c#

I'm  developing an attendance management system using finger print recognition. So what i want is comparing the two bmp images those are generated by the scanner. I've heard about neural network but i don't know how to implement the same. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to develop this from scratch, you want something like the [Digital Persona Software Development Kit.](http://www.digitalpersona.com/Developer-Tools/SDKs/Software-Development-Kits/)

There are others, but that's the one I was using tonight :)

There's also this question: [Opensource or Free Fingerprint Reader SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13555985/opensource-or-free-fingerprint-reader-sdk).

**Edited to add:**

If you can't use the [NITGEN SDK](http://nitgen.com/eng/product/enbioapi_sdk.html), then you're probably not going to succeed in your project. When you compare 'fingerprints', you're not actually comparing the images, you're comparing lists of key points (indicia) extracted from the images.

Comment: Sir actually i'm using nitgen finger scanner, and i'm not able to implement its SDK in my project

Answer (score 0):

It will take forever if you start from scratch. I used Griaule Biometrics 4 years ago making this project. It worked like a charm. Add a reference to the necessary DLL to operate the fingerprint scanner.

Answer (score -6):

I think you are looking for :

https://github.com/cameronmcefee/Image-Diff-View-Modes/commit/8e95f70c9c47168305970e91021072673d7cdad8

For Simple Approach:

```
   1: private bool ImageCompareArray(Bitmap firstImage, Bitmap secondImage) 
   2: {
   3:     bool flag = true;
   4:     string firstPixel;
   5:     string secondPixel;
   6:  
   7:     if (firstImage.Width == secondImage.Width 
   8:         && firstImage.Height == secondImage.Height)
   9:     {
  10:         for (int i = 0; i < firstImage.Width; i++)
  11:         {
  12:             for (int j = 0; j < firstImage.Height; j++)
  13:             {
  14:                 firstPixel = firstImage.GetPixel(i, j).ToString();
  15:                 secondPixel = secondImage.GetPixel(i, j).ToString();
  16:                 if (firstPixel != secondPixel)
  17:                 {
  18:                     flag = false;
  19:                     break;
  20:                 }
  21:             }
  22:         }
  23:  
  24:         if (flag == false)
  25:         {
  26:             return false;
  27:         }
  28:         else
  29:         {
  30:             return true;
  31:         }
  32:     }
  33:     else
  34:     {
  35:         return false;
  36:     }
  37: }
```

Also see : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/domgreen/archive/2009/09/06/comparing-two-images-in-c.aspx

Comment: you can not expect that the 2 images will be exactly the same. I think that's why the OP is looking for a NN or sth like that.

Comment: Indeed you can. In fact, if I were to make a finger print comparison system based on this, my first modification would be to delete the entire thing and then make something that would actually work.

Comment: The problem is that you answered the OP's question, but he was asking the wrong question; Those here who have worked with fingerprint scanners saw this, and told him what he needed to know.

So unfortunately your answer is both very right and very wrong.